# Agregar {'\n'} dentro de un string

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con react native y javascript, quiero agregar un texto con este salto: {'\n'} a dentro de un string, como muestro en esta imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me tira el error 'Invalid character' ¿alguien sabe de que forma lo puedo agregar? dejo el string abajo:

export const DATA_TREATMENT_A_DESC =
'- Prestación de servicios médico-hospitalarios, hospitalización, cirugía, atención de enfermería, servicios farmacéuticos, análisis de laboratorio radiología e imagen, estudios y análisis patológicos, terapia, rehabilitación, dieta y nutrición . {'\n'}- Creación, estudio, análisis, actualización y mantenimiento de archivo clínico. {'\n'}- Facturación y cobranza por servicios. {'\n'}- Mantenimiento de registros para seguimiento a servicios.'

Comment: Estas cerrando el string y agregando \n, y luego abriendo otro string. Intentá cambiando los ' de los extremos por "

Comment: como crees que podria agregarlo? si tengo parrafo con varios {'\n'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al iniciar el String, lo abres con comillas simples `'`, luego, para cerrarlo usas las comillas simples otra vez. si queres incrustar `{'\n'}` dentro de tu string, deberias iniciar tu string con `"` o incrustarlo de esta forma `{"\n"}`, de esta forma no alteras el inicio y el fin de tu string

Comment: gracias! si me ha funcionado

Comment: No hay de que, marca la respuesta como aceptada por favor 

Comment: @donirj en ese caso, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia-lo a comillas dobles para que imprima el carácter del salto de línea...

```
var texto = "Hole" + "\n" + "Línea Siguiente";
```